# How to Show the time for an event in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, time

In my iOS app I have to create a Digital timer (Not the system Time) in the `HH:MM:SS` format which should start from `00:00:00` on tap of a `button`, can I make use of any standard library to do so? Or I should write my own logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one thing you can do is to create a timer and remember time in which you created it.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped() {

    // Store date / time in which you tapped the button
    self.initialDate = NSDate()

    // Create timer that fires every second starting now (scheduled), and repeats
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("timerTick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Then, when you have initial stuff, you can do `timerTick` method. In here, you get current date, do difference between your stored one and current and present it:

```
func timerTick() {

    // Get calendar and components of the dates in interval <initialDate, currentDate>
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitSecond | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: self.initialDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions.allZeros)

    // In this point you have minutes, seconds and hours, you can just present it
    // "%02d:%02d:%02d" in format means "number, always at least 2 numbers, fill with zeroes if needed")
    self.label.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", components.hour, components.minute, components.second)
}
```

If you want to stop the timer, you can do it by calling `self.timer.invalidate()`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Foundation framework includes the `NSDateFormatter` class (and the `NSDate` data type) which does just this.

Comment: Thanx for your reply @Clafou,, I wont be Just showing the system date in this format, I have to create my own clock which will start from 00:00:01  , How could I do this?

Comment: Oh OK! Glad to see other people answered that!

Answer (score 0):

In your .m file add these properties:

```
#import "MyVC.h"

@interface MyVC()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer* timer; // our timer
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger secondsPassed; // how many seconds have been passed since the start of the timer
@end
```

In `viewDidLoad` or in the `IBAction` method of your `UIButton`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myLabel.text = @"00:00:00"; // start text 

    // invoke updateTimer every second 
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats: YES];
}
```

This method will be called every second to update the UILabel

```
-(void) updateTimer{
    NSInteger hours, minutes, seconds;
   // increase the passed seconds
    self.secondsPassed++;

    // calculate the hours, minutes, seconds from the total number of seconds
    hours =  self.secondsPassed / 3600;
    minutes = ( self.secondsPassed % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = ( self.secondsPassed %3600) % 60;

    // update the label with the time
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02zd:%02zd:%02zd", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

alternatively you can use [MZTimerLabel](https://github.com/mineschan/MZTimerLabel)